# Why can't I store a PriorityQueue into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema, priority-queue

Recently I have decided to replace arrays with priority queues for storing my list of jobs for a user into MongoDB. I use NodeJS and ExpressJS for backend. The priority queue I attempted to store is from an external package which can be installed by running the following command in terminal:

```
yarn add js-priority-queue
```

For some reason the priority queue works perfectly prior to storing it into MongoDB. However, the next time I attempt to take it out of MongoDB and use it, its functionality is missing. I declare its type as Schema.Types.Mixed in the Schema. Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to store instantiated class objects into MongoDB?

Comment: Storing probably works, reading not so much.

Comment: So there's no possible way to read it?

Comment: You can read but you would get the data stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when you store things in MongoDB they are stored as *extended* JSON (EJSON) in binary format (BSON)

```js
    const { EJSON } = require('bson');    
    const test = EJSON.stringify({a: new Date(), foo:function(){console.log('foo');}})
    console.log(test) // "{"a":{"$date":"2020-07-07T14:45:49.475Z"}}"
```

So any sort of function is lost.